# Transforming the format of a JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I have a jsonObject query from SQL Server below:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "code": "c1_1",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "code": "c1_2",
      "value": false
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I convert its format to:

```
{
  "list": {
    "c1_1": "1",
    "c1_2": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems simple. Do you have any code so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a json list of objects, and you are trying to convert it to a dictionary

There are other ways to do this, however you could do this

```
public class Something
{
   public string code { get; set; }
   public object value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public List<Something> List { get; set; }
}

public class NewObject
{
   public Dictionary<string,object> List { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// convert it to C# concrete classes
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

// convert to dictionary 
var dictionary = rootObject.List.ToDictionary(x => x.code, x => x.value);

// create new object with dictionary
var newObject = new NewObject() {List = dictionary};

// output
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "List": {
    "c1_1": "1",
    "c1_2": false
  }
}
```

**[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U35Gh8)**

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a Dictionary from an IEnumerable.

- [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)
- [JsonConvert.SerializeObject Method (Object)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)
- http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), you can transform your JSON like this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj["list"] = new JObject(
    obj["list"].Children<JObject>()
               .Select(jo => new JProperty((string)jo["code"], jo["value"]))
);
json = obj.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KvGUWA